# type object 'word' has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python, django, forms

I am building a form for users to update a field in the object.

It is a page with a list of forms to update different instances of the model. Most of the forms work without error, but when I tried to submit the first form in the page, I get an error: type object 'word' has no attribute 'update'. I do not have a class called 'word' and this error only appears if I try to submit the first form on the page. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

In template:

```
{% for corr in correction_list %}

  <tr><td>{{corr.correction_author}}</td><td>{{corr.time | date:"m/d/Y"}}</td>
      <td>{{corr.corrected_word.kwicl}}</td><td>{{corr.corrected_word.keyword}}</td>
      <td>{{corr.corrected_word.kwicr}}</td><td>{{corr.corrected_word.choice1}}</td>
      <td>{{corr.corrected_word.choice2}}</td><td>{{corr.corrected_word.choice3}}</td>
      <td>{{corr.corrected_word.correct_choice}}</td><td>{{corr.corrected_word.manually_entered_word}}</td>
      <td>{{corr.correction_made}}</td><td>{{corr.correction_word}}</td>
      <td><form action="../approval/" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              Decision:
              <select name="approved">
                <option value=1>Approve</option>
                  <option value=2>Reject</option>
                  <option value=0>Hold</option>
              </select><br>
                <input type="text" name="corrected_word" value={{corr.corrected_word.file_position}} hidden="True"/>

                <input type="number" name="correction_made" value={{corr.correction_made}} hidden="True"/>
                {% if corr.correction_word %}
                <input type="text" name="correction_word" value={{corr.correction_word}} hidden="True"/>
                {% else%}
                <input type="text" name="correction_word" value="" hidden="True"/>
                {% endif %}

                 <input type="submit"/></form></td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In views.py:

```
def submit_approval(request):
if hasattr(request, 'user') and request.user.is_authenticated():
    corrected_word = request.POST['corrected_word']
    updateword = item.objects.filter(file_position=corrected_word)[0]
    correction_made = request.POST['correction_made']
    correction_word = request.POST['correction_word']
    approval = request.POST['approved']
    corr = correction.objects.filter(corrected_word=updateword).filter(correction_made=correction_made).filter(correction_word=correction_word)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        for entry in corr:
            entry.approved = approval
            entry.save()
        return HttpResponse('thanks')

    return render(request, "revision.html")
```

In urls.py:

```
url(r'^approval/$', 'english.views.submit_approval'),
```

Traceback:

```
Request Method: POST  
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/revision/

Django Version: 1.8.3  
Python Version: 2.7.5  
Installed Applications:  
('django.contrib.admin',  
 'django.contrib.auth',  
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',  
 'django.contrib.sessions',  
 'django.contrib.messages',  
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',  
 'english')  
Installed Middleware:  
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',  
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',  
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',  
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',  
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')  


Traceback:  
File "/Users/vl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)  
File "/Users/vl/english/english/views.py" in revision
  151.             word.update(approved=formdata)  

Exception Type: AttributeError at /revision/  
Exception Value: type object 'word' has no attribute 'update'
```

Comment: what's the stack trace?

Comment: Can you give us the full stack trace, please? Maybe this exception is thrown from another module, maybe it's from yours... So give us more information.

Comment: @VickieLi please edit the question to include the stack trace, rather than have it as a comment

Comment: The traceback is clearly saying that the error is happening in the `revision` view, not in `submit_approval`

Comment: Thanks! It seems that only my first form in the template is mapping to the wrong view. What could cause that?

Comment: why is your action `../approval/`? Shouldn't it just be a url?

Comment: It's a url:  url(r'^approval/$', 'english.views.submit_approval'),

Comment: @VickieLi: Daniel has already pointed out that your error is happening in `"/Users/vl/english/english/views.py"` if you look closely at the stack trace. We couldn't possibly understand why you have the problem unless you show us what's inside that file.

Comment: @ShangWang: Thanks for your response! I have found out the source of the error: the first form in the template is mapped to a view in views.py called 'revision', which is not intended for this form. But why is it mapping to that view when the action for the form clearly says '../approval/'?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your form `action` code. It's generally a bad practice to hard code any url in django. If your url changes, you have to change everywhere. Check the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url.

According to the doc, the best practice would be:

1. Give your url a name to refer to:

`url(r'^approval/$', 'english.views.submit_approval', name="submit-approval"),`

2. In the action of your form, refer to that url:

`<form action="{% url 'submit-approval' %}" method="POST"></form>`

Comment: Thanks for the response! That was very helpful. But I don't think that is the problem, since all of the forms are submitting correctly except the first one rendered by the page.